# CSS: hide element when container too narrow to let it be seen in its entirety

Tags: html, css

Suppose I have an outer container of unknown fixed width, and an inner element, like so:

```
<div id="outer"><div id="inner">hide me when #outer is too small</div></div>
```

Is there a way I can make `#inner` entirely hidden (not just clipped) when `#outer` is not wide enough to show it in its entirety using pure CSS?

Comment: What is the content of #inner and how do you determine it is clipped? Is it text, image, iframe...?

Comment: @remibreton: In my specific case, it's just text.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not possible via pure CSS, since you cannot provide conditions (if you don't use IE .htc files;) ). You need to use JS for that and compare both elements width.

For text you can use: `text-overflow:clip|ellispis;`

Edit:

```
#inner {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

could be helpful.

EDIT:

I [prepared a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/poikl/gbQpb/) for rampion's solution. Note that the `text-overflow` with a custom string is only working in FF. Additionally, `text-overflow` is not standardized yet. [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-css3-text-20021024/#text-overflow-mode) currently states it as `text-overflow-mode` in [its working draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-css3-text-20021024/#text-overflow-mode). See also an [interesting article at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/text-overflow).

Comment: +1 thanks for teaching me about text-overflow.  Your answer led me to figuring out [my hack](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9669980/9859).

Comment: I also usually use "white-space: nowrap" to have ellipsis to show up for more than 1-word texts.

Answer (score 18):

This is possible without JS through floats and adding a helper inner element:

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="helper"></div>
  <div class="inner">hide me when .outer is too small</div>
</div>
```

and css:

```
.outer {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.helper {
  width: 1px;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.inner {
  float: left;
}
```

The inner element will now wrap under the helper if it doesn't fit within the width of the outer element, which with `.helper` having `height: 100%` and `.outer` having `overflow: hidden` results in the inner element not being visible.

You could *remove* the 1px helper width by using `width: 0.01px` instead, but I'm not sure if that runs into browser compatibility issues.

Comment: I believe that this should be the accepted answer since it does solve the problem as stated and it is a "css solution" as requested by the poster.

Comment: Hi nemuri. So you can hide elements when the outer is too narrow. Can you do the opposite? I mean can you hide elements when the outer is too wide using pure css?

Answer (score 1):

[Christoph's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9668730/9859) is probably best in the general case, but in my case, I knew the text content but not the container width, which let me add an additional layer of trickery:

Altering the HTML slightly:

```
<div id="first" class="container">
  <div><span>first_text_section</span></div>
</div>
<div id="second" class="container">
  <div><span>second_text_section</span></div>
</div>
<div id="third" class="container">
  <div><span>third_text_section</span></div>
</div>
```

And using the following CSS:

```
.container > div {
  color: transparent; /* don't show the text-overflow content */
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 1em;
  width: 100%;
}
/* use the actual text to get the measurement right for hiding */
#first > div { text-overflow: "first_text_section"; }
#second > div { text-overflow: "second_text_section"; }
#third > div { text-overflow: "third_text_section"; }
.container > div > span {
  color: black; /* do show the span when possible */
}
```

Then as the width of the container changes, the full text is either hidden or shown appropriately.  If the text contained is more than one word, the text is hidden word by word, so that's something to be aware of.

Comment: To be honest, I don't know what your code is supposed to do. You don't need all that fancy rules for hiding the overflowing text. Normally `overflow:hidden;` is all you need.

Comment: @Christoph: the fancy rules make any truncated words invisible.

Comment: First of all: your text-overflow rules are invalid. There are only values clip or ellipsis allowed. Second, the rule: `color:transparent;` never applies, because it is overridden by `color:black;`. The only thing which hides the text is your `overflow:hidden;` rule.

Comment: @Christoph: Nope, [string values are allowed in some browsers](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp).  `color:transparent` applies when the `text-overflow` kicks in.  [Try it out in FF](https://gist.github.com/2024561).  It is, however, not terribly portable :(

Comment: I'll try that asa i have a computer in range. Please never use w3schools as reference! [it is full of errors. See this link.](http://w3fools.com)

Comment: well, i tried what you did, and it works, but only in FF. See my edit, i wrote a fiddle for that. In every case it's interesting, but will surely depend on the further development of css3 text-module. Feel free to accept my answer, if it helped you;)

Comment: Well this seems to work only for static sizes, right? I tried with div widths set to 33% and resizing the window does not change the text (otherwise it would be super cool =)).

Comment: @alexandroid: perhaps - I hadn't tested that.